# Call willrotate method for added subview controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, uiinterfaceorientation

I have added one view controller to my first view controller as aa subview by using `self.view add subview:secondview` now when I'll rotate the device

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

method calls for only parent view Now I also want to call that method for child view controller so i can make required changes in child view controller also.
 So for that what I have to do??

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the secondView a UIViewController or just a UIView object?

Comment: I would have thought that you'd want to `pushViewController`, `presentViewControllerAnimated` or `addChildViewController`. Don't try to send these rotation events yourself, but rather let iOS do the work for you.

Comment: BTW, you say that secondview is a `UIViewController`. Are you sure that you're really using a view controller as a parameter to addSubview?!?

Comment: If you examine the [addSubview documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCCEII), you'll see that you should be sending it a UIView and not a UIViewController. I'm surprised that that's working at all. And I'm surprised that the compiler is not complaining (unless you are using a variable of type `id`, which is a really bad idea itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [WWDC 2011 Session 102](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) on view controller containment, they mention that a failure to keep one's view controller hierarchy synchronized with the view hierarchy can result in rotation events problems. They explicitly point out that if you just grab a view controller's view and add it as a subview of the main view, without adding the controller, itself, to the view controller hierarchy, you won't get these rotation events. In that WWDC session, they also suggest that if you want to "future-proof" your app, you'll want to manage view controllers properly.

From a pragmatic perspective, this means that as you go from one view to another, that you really should be transitioning the view controllers. Most commonly this means using `pushViewController` or `presentViewControllerAnimated` (formerly `presentModalViewController`). Or you can use view controller containment (see that WWDC session or look at the very brief comments about containment in the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81)). But don't just grab the view from another view controller and just add it as a subview of the current view.

If you pursue view controller containment, at a minimum, you could add your child view's controller to the hierarchy via:

```
[self addChildViewController:childController];
[childController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```